# When i upload a file on a Server, it shows an error

Tags: android

When i am uploading file on server through Multipart library.Multipart is showing me file upload successfully but when i saw file in server there is no file on server.

I am using below code.Please check it where i am missing some code or anything else

```
  String API_URL_POST_COMPLAINT 
  ="";

    String responseResult = "0";
    try {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("lusername", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userId = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(result.getUri().toString());
        String realPath = ImageFilePath.getPath(MainActivity.this, uri);
        File picturePathFile  = new File(realPath);

        String complaint="Hello";
        String apiUrl = API_URL_POST_COMPLAINT + "Token=" + "isuotb4hmtXrOcB0IhHdkDbL7NReoacMpYDHWRUFtWYj7l-Ps2Y=" + "&WOID="+URLEncoder.encode("52326", "UTF-8") +"&DocTitle="+URLEncoder.encode("Hi", "UTF-8")+"&FileName="+picturePathFile;
        apiUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        apiUrl.replaceAll("\n", "%20");
        MyMultipartRequest multipart = new MyMultipartRequest(getApplicationContext(), apiUrl);
        multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "This is my test Header field");
        multipart.addFormField("Token", "isuotb4hmtXrOcB0IhHdkDbL7NReoacMpYDHWRUFtWYj7l-Ps2Y=");
        multipart.addFormField("WOID", "52326");
        multipart.addFormField("DocTitle", "Hello");
        multipart.addFilePart("FileName", picturePathFile);
        System.out.println("complaintFile = " + complaint);
        System.out.println("picturePathFile = " + picturePathFile);
        System.out.println("complaintFile = " + picturePathFile.getName());
        String responsePost = multipart.finish();
        System.out.println("responsePost = " + responsePost);
        return responsePost;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseResult = "0";
    }
    return responseResult;
```

.Net code is here

```
[HttpPost]
public Result UploadDoc(string Token, int WOID, string DocTitle, string 
FileName)
{
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent() || 
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count == 0)
   return new Result(Result.ResultCode.NoAction, "File not found");

byte[] lBytes = new byte[HttpContext.Current.Request.Files(0).ContentLength - 
 1 + 1];
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Files(0).InputStream.Read(lBytes, 0,  
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Files(0).ContentLength - 1);

 Result lRes = UserClass.GetUserFromToken(Token);
 if (lRes.NoSuccess)
   return lRes;
 UserClass lUser = (UserClass)lRes.RetInfo;
 if (lUser.RoleType == UserClass.UserRoleType.Read_Only)
   return lRes.Init(Result.ResultCode.NoAction, "Permission Denied for User 
 Role");
  if (WorkOrderClass.SearchByUser(WOID.ToString(), lUser, true).Length == 0)
   lRes.Init(Result.ResultCode.NoAction, "Permission Denied on WO");
 return (new DocumentClass() { WorkOrderID = WOID, UploadedBy = lUser.UserID, 
 DocTitle = DocTitle.Trim(), FileName = FileName, Doc = lBytes 
 }).InsertIntoDB;
  }
```

Comment: Please **STOP!** defacing your post title!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the file type (what kind of file you are uploading). And try to upload with okhttp.

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private class FileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = getOkHttpClient();
            MultipartBody.Builder data = new MultipartBody.Builder();
            data.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
            MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

            data.addFormDataPart("FileName","file.png", 
            RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, picturePathFile));

            RequestBody requestBody = data.build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("Your URL").post(requestBody)
                    .build();
            Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            result = response.body().string().toString();

            Log.e("Result : ", result);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (response != null) {
            //Do something with your response.
        }
    }
}

public OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Do you want full code for uploading file via multipart?